# Can't set custom BackgroundColor on UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm using this code to customize the colour of my cell's background view:

```
UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0 green:255.0 blue:255.0 alpha:1.0];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
```

The thing is, it doesn't work. This code though, works perfectly fine:

```
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

What's the problem here? Can't I customize the colour of a cell to my liking? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Not seeing the color, as in the color is transparent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to set Cell Background with this Delegate:-

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView
  willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell
forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{

   // UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];  // get your background image

    UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:1.0]; //if you want to set color then use this line

  //  UIColor *backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage: img];
    cell.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
    cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Your table look like:-

[image]

[Taking an RGB color and normalizing it with UIColor on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/821199/taking-an-rgb-color-and-normalizing-it-with-uicolor-on-the-iphone)

```
Your values are between 0 and 255. Use them to create a UIColor:

    float r; float g; float b; float a;

    [UIColor colorWithRed:r/255.f
                    green:g/255.f
                     blue:b/255.f    
                    alpha:a/255.f];
```

Comment: What are those /255.0 for anyway? Can't I just copy and paste the color data from Photoshop directly to UIColor?

Comment: In computers, the component values are often stored as integer numbers in the range 0 to 255, the range that a single 8-bit byte can offer. These are often represented as either decimal or hexadecimal numbers. read for more at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model

Comment: So as far as I understand, to get the r value of 230 in Photoshop I have to use UIColor colorWithRed:230/255.f ? Or is it something different?

Comment: @SergiusGee your photoshop r value is between 0 to 255 you never get greter then 255 so in 8-byte convert and crate UIColor in iphone you must your r value device with 255 so when you crate color in objective c with RGB you device if with 255 hope now you understood. `UIColor colorWithRed:230/255.f`  is a correct way

Comment: Great! Thanks for an answer and for the overwhelming explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Just change :

```
UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
cell.contentView.backgroundColor = cellBackgroundColor;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor
```

you can make a custom view and can change the complete backgroundview

```
UIView *backgroundViewForCell = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
backgroundViewForCell.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"row-bg.png"]];
UIView *selectedBackgroundViewForCell = [[[UIView alloc] init] autorelease];
selectedBackgroundViewForCell.backgroundColor = [[UIColor blueColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:.2];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundViewForCell;
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundViewForCell;
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can add `cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]` before you set your color.

The reason is that the backgroundview is at the bottom. The contentview is at the top.

**Other LOgic IS**

```
UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1];

[cell.contentView addSubview:myBackView];

[myBackView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

you are on the right track. You just need to replace your color code with this

```
UIColor *cellBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255.0/255.0 green:255.0/255.0 blue:255.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
```

Enjoy Programming!!